# How to set Last Name equal empty in Skype?

Tags: windows-7, skype

Is there some way to set `last name field` as empty in Skype? I tried write `&nbsp;` in `last name textbox`, but It is does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should open the page (https://secure.skype.com/portal/profile), then click "Edit" button, then open the source code of this page (use the firebug plagin), then find the folowing input tag:

```
<input id="lastname" class="requiredName maxlengthName minlengthName semibold error" type="text" data-current="" value="" data-tabindex="true" name="lastname" style="display: inline;" tabindex="14">
```

then delete the path of class - `requiredName` 
for example:

```
<input id="lastname" class="maxlengthName minlengthName semibold error" type="text" data-current="" value="" data-tabindex="true" name="lastname" style="display: inline;" tabindex="14">
```

and then delete you last name and click "Save" button.

Comment: Firebug is not a requirement here, <kbd>Right Click</kbd> -> `Inspect Element` should suffice (at least in Chrome & Firefox)!

Comment: @jjk_charles, yeah, but almost everyone has firebug. Therefore, this method is okay for me.